# appId in Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

what is the importance of "appId" in the url for facebook javascript sdk?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=162509917148524&amp;xfbml=1">
    </script>
    <fb:like href="spartanp.github.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
    </fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this parameter is just for organisation - it allows facebook to assign permissions to a specific app instead of the website itself in a database, maybe even monitoring traffic. It basically assigns an app to your website.